# Best practice to indirectly connect to remote MySQL server in Python

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have a Raspberry Pi collecting temperature measurements once every minute and I would like a Python script running locally on the Pi to upload these to my MySQL database hosted on a rented web server.

The server does not accept remote connections to the database (something I cannot change) so I cannot connect directly. I'm wondering how best to deal with this: what is the best practice?

I could connect to the server and database through SSH or maybe call a PHP script sitting on the server and provide it with the SQL statement to execute but I'm not sure that is the best way.

Comment: Both is possible. There is no "best". That completely depends on your personal preferences. The advantage of directly accessing the MySQL server through an ssh tunnel is that it is crunchy, using some listening script on the server side, most likely inside an http server has the benefit that you will create an abstract API you can reuse for other things.

Comment: Yeah as @arkascha said, there are no real "best practices" for this kind of thing. You're basically just scripting right now and not building an enterprise grade system, so don't bother overthinking things. Personally I would just rsync the files locally to the mysql server and then write a python script to convert the files to SQL.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you very much!